# Docusign Gen for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapextoolkit

I am using Salesforce DocuSign gen product. I have a requirement to generate documents systematically in Salesforce and associate it with one of the custom objects (lic_documents__c is a child object for another custom object). I could not find the right method for generating documents using Docusign Apex toolkit. Does anyone know if there are any methods available in DocuSign Apex toolkit to generate document? Salesforce DocuSign esignature managed package has got createEnvelop and sendEnvelop methods. I am not sure if createEnvelop method could be leveraged for my use case. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm wanting to do this same thing, did you find a way at all?